# How to trigger Required Field Validation when tabbing through DatePicker form control?

Tags: angular

In my angular app, I have added Required Field Validation to a DatePicker control:

```
<div class="form-group"
  [ngClass]="{
    'has-required':['injuryDate'].untouched && ['injuryDate'].invalid, 
    'has-error':['injuryDate'].touched && ['injuryDate'].invalid}">

        <label for="injuryDate">
            {{lblInjuryDate}}
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>

        <datepicker formControlName="injuryDate" id="injuryDate" name="dtpInjuryDate">
        </datepicker>

        <span class="error-block"
          *ngIf="['injuryDate'].touched && ['injuryDate'].invalid">  
            {{requiredInjuryDate}}
        </span>
</div>
```

The validation works as expected when I click into DatePicker & do not select a date:

[image: dateValidation]

But when I just tab through the DatePicker control, the above error message isn't displayed.

Can someone please show me how to trigger this validation when I tab through the control? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is not displayed because of: `['injuryDate'].touched`.

By default the touched property is FALSE but when you leave the input the touched value is set to TRUE permanently.